# Kubenetes - For web based applications, does it support cookie based routing so as to route subset of customers to the new version of the application?

Tags: kubernetes, canary-deployment

Suppose there is a version 1.0 of the web application running in production. You want to deploy new version 2.0 side by side of the production version 1.0. You want to route traffic from subset of users/customers to the new version. In other words, how to achieve real canary releases (as defined by [this](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html) article) for web based applications on Kubernetes.

Kubernetes [documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/managing-deployments/#canary-deployments) talks about canary deployments but there is no mention about how to achieve user based routing. Is it possible to implement sticky load balancing based on cookie with the existing load balancing support provided by Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Canary deployment on Kubernetes involve deploying Pods of the same App but of different versions: if you have 5 Pods for an App for example, one of them could be a new version, and 1/5 of your traffic would be directed to this new version.

To achieve user based canary deployment, you could use sticky sessions on your Service, with

`sessionAffinity: ClientIP`

That will insure that when a client connected, it will always end up on the same Pod (if the IP remains the same)

I don't think there is a 'cookie' based way to assign traffic.

Comment: yes, but, there is no control on routing logic - if I want to route only selected subset of users to new Pod that would not be possible. I was thinking of setting a canary cookie on user login and then use that cookie to route the user to a canary pod. I guess that is not possible if I am using Kubernetes provided load balancing.

Comment: i don't think it is. a cookie would have to be parsed somewhere to proxy the traffic where you want. that seems like a very custom solution